# How can I remove the extra iframe space at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

This is my first question on stackoverflow. What I want to do is to create an iframe into test div with javascript and add html code in it. Also I want to resize iframe's height dynamically. The code below works good for me only if I set dynamic_div's height more than 150px. If the height of the dynamic_div less than 150 it automatically sets iframe's height to 150. How can I fix this problem ?

P.S : html code in the html variable is dynamic. So I can not change anything in it.

Many Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test" style="border: 1px solid;"></div>
<script text="text/javascript">
var html = "<html><head></head><body><div id=\"container\" style=\"text-align:center;padding:8px 0;background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px dashed;\"> <div id=\"dynamic_div\" style=\"width:100%;height:50px\">Some Content</div></body></html>";

function ui_aa(element_id,content){ // create an iframe and add txt into it.
    var iframe = document.getElementById(element_id).appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')),
    doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframe.style.cssText = "width:100%";
    iframe.frameBorder = 0;
    iframe.scrolling= 'no';
    doc.open().write(content);
    doc.close(); 
    doc.body.style.cssText = "margin:0px;padding:0px;height:100%";
    var height = doc.body.scrollHeight;
    iframe.height = height;
};
ui_aa('test',html);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe gets a height value for unknown reason to me, to give it a height value such as `0` did the trick, The `doc.body.style.cssText` overwrites the height value to `100%` anyway, so you don't need to worry.

```
function ui_aa(element_id,content){ // create an iframe and add txt into it.
    iframe.height= '0';
};
```

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h21nj5jt/)

Answer (score 0):

Because of your `<div id="container">`

Automatically it wont be as tall as your iframe.
Add some style to it.

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Tamas but It didn't work.